Blockchain Layer 2 Attacks
I'm interested in learning more about blockchain security. I've studied the vulnerabilities in Layer 1 and improved my skills. After focusing on smart contract vulnerabilities in Layer 1, I want to develop my skills in Layer 2 smart contracts. However, I'm having difficulty finding resources. Do you know of any sources that detail past attacks on Layer 2? What types of vulnerabilities occur in Layer 2 smart contracts, and are there any web platforms you know of where I can practice?

If you are refering to Ethereum L2s smart contracts, they will be the exact same as L1 contracts. Contracts on Ethereum (L1), Arbitrum (L2), and Optimism (L2) are all written in the same language, Solidity. Other programming languages are used, such as Vyper but Solidity accounts for 92.22% of all contracts, while Vyper is used for 1.27%.
There are some upcoming L2 specific languages such as Arbitrum Stylus which is a Rust-based Arbitrum compatible language, though not widely used at the moment.
If you have already know smart contract vulnerabilities on L1s, you should be all set on L2s, as they are the exact same. If you want to study previous attacks, I would use defillama.com/hacks, as they document almost every blockchain hack. Best of luck in your learning!

Thank you for your answer and suggestion. I visited the website but couldn't find any documentation, where can I find it?

I am asking for documentation of hacks...
